# Populate an observableArray from ajax call

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Upon click of "Add" button, result from db will be fetched.
I want this result to be populated in observableArray or computed (computed for future).

I am clueless on how to populate the observable array. Below is the code for ajax call

KNOCKOUTJS

```
self.addToCartViaProdList = function (item, event) 
{
    /*get current item index*/
    /*in dom element $index() is enough but in viewModel a context is to be obtained*/
    var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
    var index = context.$index();
    var incQty = self.prodList()[index].ProductQty();
    var prodID = self.prodList()[index].ProductID();

    var verProdInCombo = ko.toJS({"prodID":prodID});
    //check product in combos
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: '**************ProdID.php', 
        type: "post",
        data: verProdInCombo,
        success: function(result) 
        {
            /*The result is in below format*/
            /***************
            "{"ComboName":"SinglePack","ComboItemsName":"Aloo Tikki Burger,Mango Lassi,Tomato Soup","ComboItemsID":"101_1_11,1105_11_110,901_9_90","ComboTotalPrice":"90.25"}"
            ********************/
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, status){
            alert(xhr);
            alert(status);
        }
    });
};
```

I am getting the success result, but all my attempts to put this data in observableArray has not yielded any fruitful result.

I have tried saving the result in localSession. And then using a computed variable to pick values from that localSession,

Then I have tried to use ko.mapping.fromJS(result), this didnot work either

I want to display the list as received from server in a div as follows:

HTML CODE

```
<div class="comboSeg" >
    <div data-bind="foreach: comboDataList">
        <div data-bind="text: ComboName">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: ComboItemsName">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: ComboTotalPrice">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The different version of knockoutjs tried are:

VERSION 1: Saving data in local session and using computed

```
self.comboDataList = ko.computed(function()
{
    var comboDataItems = [];
    if (self.comboValChange() == "DO" && localStorage.getItem("comboDataItem") != null)
    {
        var dataSaved = localStorage.getItem("comboDataItem");
        comboDataItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataSaved, function(item)
        {
            return new ComboList(item.ComboName, item.ComboItemsName, item.ComboItemsID, item.ComboTotalPrice);
        });

        comboDataItems.push(dataSaved);
    }

    return comboDataItems;
},this);

//Ajax call is as follows:

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: '***************ProdID.php', 
        type: "post",
        data: verProdInCombo,
        success: function(result) 
        {
            localStorage.removeItem("comboDataItem");
            localStorage.setItem("comboDataItem",result);
            //Forcing the computed function to be called, just a workaround
            self.comboValChange("");
            self.comboValChange("DO");
        }, //Result will contain whatever server will send back as a mesage
        error: function(xhr, status){
            alert(xhr);
            alert(status);
        }
    });
```

VERSION 2 : Pushing the success msg received in comboDataList

```
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: '*************ProdID.php', 
        type: "post",
        data: verProdInCombo,
        success: function(result)
        {
            self.comboDataList.push(result);
            //Also tried below one
            //self.comboDataList.push(ko.toJS(result));
        }, //Result will contain whatever server will send back as a mesage
        error: function(xhr, status){
            alert(xhr);
            alert(status);
        }
    });
```

Now I have enabled the denug in browser I got this error message for both the versions:

Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return ComboName }"
Message: ComboName is not defined

Comment: You mention having tried two versions for the `success` handler function, but haven't included the code or the details as to *why* it didn't work or what error it gave. Please include those so we can help you fix the problem.

Comment: you json looks just fine check this sample here https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27832/ . more info is appreciated .

Comment: @Jeroen: I did not get any error. Somehow the comboDataList remain empty. What I want to know that after each ajax call does the whole View model refreshes itself? Currently I am out of office. I will attach the code couple of hours later. Apologies for not doing the same rightaway.

Comment: Well, at this moment, the list would remain empty because all code in the `success` handler is commented out ;-). If you add the code it's quite likely we'll be able to help you. - In any case, to answer your other question: Knockout will update the view automatically if you change *observables*, but not if you overwrite a property/variable that contains an observable with a new one. (Again though: easier to explain in the context of actual code.)

Answer (score 2):

Just plug the observableArray in *as the success function of your Ajax call*:

```
$.ajax
({
    url: '**************ProdID.php', 
    type: "post",
    data: verProdInCombo,
    success: self.comboDataList, 
    error: function(xhr, status){
        alert(xhr);
        alert(status);
    }
});
```

That assumes you don't need to update the individual elements inside rows of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting below error <Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return ComboName }"
Message: ComboName is not defined>

Comment: Though in the debug I can see ComboName is present in the json received as string.

Comment: Show us the JSON you're getting from the server. It is the most important information for answering your question.

Comment: This is the json I am getting in string format <"{"ComboName":"SinglePack","ComboItemsName":"Aloo Tikki Burger,Mango Lassi,Tomato Soup","ComboItemsID":"101_1_11,1105_11_110,901_9_90","ComboTotalPrice":"90.25"}">

Comment: Possibly adding `dataType:'json'` to your `ajax` parameters will help. You need to know whether success is getting the string value or the JS object. Play with it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have answered it, how I got it working. Let me know if there is any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working, guess this is not the best method.
Simply pushing the success JSON object into observableArray was not reflected in my html page, hence I used computed to get it done.

The KNOCKOUT Code is

```
self.comboDataList = ko.computed(function()
{
    var comboDataItems = [];
    //self.comboValChange() an observable variable just to invoke the computed function everytime there is update
    if (self.comboValChange() == "DO" && localStorage.getItem("comboItems") != null)
    {
        var dataSaved = ko.utils.parseJson(localStorage.getItem("comboItems"));
        comboDataItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataSaved, function(item)
        {
            return new ComboList(item.ComboName, item.ComboItemsName, item.ComboItemsID, item.ComboTotalPrice);
        });

        comboDataItems.push(dataSaved);
    }

    return comboDataItems;
},this);


//The ajax call
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: '**************ProdID.php', 
        type: "post",
        data: verProdInCombo,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result) 
        {
            //using localStorage to store the result
            localStorage.removeItem("comboItems");
            localStorage.setItem("comboItems", ko.toJSON(result));
            //updating so that everytime computed is called
            self.comboValChange("");
            self.comboValChange("DO");
        }, //Result will contain whatever server will send back as a mesage
        error: function(xhr, status){
            alert(xhr);
            alert(status);
        }
    });
```

The HTML is:

```
    <div class="comboSeg" >
        <div data-bind="foreach: comboDataList">
            <div data-bind="text: ComboName">
            </div>
            <div data-bind="text: ComboItemsName">
            </div>
            <div data-bind="text: ComboTotalPrice">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The structure of JSON is:

```
"{"ComboName":"SinglePack","ComboItemsName":"Aloo Tikki Burger,Mango Lassi,Tomato Soup","ComboItemsID":"101_1_11,1105_11_110,901_9_90","ComboTotalPrice":"90.25"}"‌
```

Hence the view model will be:

```
function ComboList(ComboName, ComboItemsName, ComboItemsID, ComboTotalPrice)
{
    this.ComboName = ko.observable(ComboName);
    this.ComboItemsName = ko.observable(ComboItemsName);
    this.ComboItemsID = ko.observable(ComboItemsID);
    this.ComboTotalPrice = ko.observable(ComboTotalPrice);
}
```